# Get swiftmailer to ignore bad emails in php

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I have a maximum of 5 emails that are to be sent through Swift Mailer but I never know how many of them will be invalid. 
The emails that are invalid =" "

I was wondering if there was a way to get swift mail to ignore the invalid emails instead of giving a Fatal error and not sending anything. I looked online and I saw that they mentioned that i should attempt to catch the bad emails before but i didn't quite understand the syntax or what they where trying to say, Anyway here is my code so far

//send the welcome letter
    function send_email($info){

```
    //format each email
    $body = format_email($info,'html');
    $body_plain_txt = format_email($info,'txt');

    //setup the mailer
    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
    $message ->setSubject('Your Party Information');
    $message ->setFrom(array('noreply@stackoverflow.net' => 'noreply@stackoverflow.net'));
    $message ->setTo(array($info['Email1'],$info['Email2'],$info['Email3'],$info['Email4'],$info['Email5'] => $info['$firstname']));

    $message ->setBody($body_plain_txt);
    $message ->addPart($body, 'text/html');

    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    return $result;

}

$emails1 = $user2['Email'] or " ";
$emails2 = $user2['Email'] or " ";
$emails3 = $user2['Email'] or " ";
$emails4 = $user2['Email'] or " ";
$emails5 = $user2['Email'] or " ";
```

Comment: It's not the answer, but you're assigning `$user2['Email']` to five different variables.

Comment: my bad forgot to change the numbers on user it should correspond to the emails number

Answer (score 2):

How about simply stripping the invalid emails beforehand, by checking with `filter_var` if the emails are valid?

```
...

$emails = array();
if (filter_var($info['Email1'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    $emails[] = $info['Email1'];
if (filter_var($info['Email2'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    $emails[] = $info['Email2'];
if (filter_var($info['Email3'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    $emails[] = $info['Email3'];
if (filter_var($info['Email4'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    $emails[] = $info['Email4'];
if (filter_var($info['Email5'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    $emails[$info['Email5']] = $info['$firstname'];

...

$message ->setTo($emails);
```

Comment: I'm confused to how this works i tried just plain copying and pasting, it stopped giving me the error message but no emails are sent.

Comment: @user2444298 It uses the `filter_var` function to check through the different emails, and if they validate it'll add it to the `$emails` array. Only emails that have been validated get added to the `$emails` array, hence when using `$message->setTo($emails)` (if the syntax is right in your example; I don't use swiftmailer), then this will mean we've stripped out (or rather, never added) emails that are not valid to the array. If you want to test what emails *have* been validated, you can either use `print_r($emails)` after all the `filter_var`ing, or use `var_dump($emails)`.